# How to correctly use Unicode and UTF-8 special characters in Node and browser js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, utf-8

So i have this character:

`MAHJONG TILE EAST WIND` Which has the Unicode point `U+1F000 (U+D83C U+DC00)` and the UTF-8 encoding `F0 9F 80 80`

My question is how to I escape this in javascript?

I see `\uff00` all the time, but that is for `ASCII` as 8 bytes will only take you up to 255.  Just putting `\u1F000'` returns the (incorrect) `'ἀ0'` and trying to fill in the extra bytes with `0`s just returns `\u0001F000'`. How do I escape values that are higher (such as my above character?).

And how do I escape not just the Unicode point but also the UTF-8 encoding?

Taking on to this, I have noticed that the node REPL is able to show many Unicode values but not some (such as Emoji) even when my terminal window (mac) normally could. Is there any rhyme or reason to this

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the char using \uXXXX x2 (for 32-bit values) format.

To use UTF-8 strings look into [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FTyped_arrays) and [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) / [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder). They are fairly new so you may need to use polyfill in some browsers.

## Example

```js
document.write('<h1>\uD83C\uDC00</h1>');
```

Comment: I see and so for code points where two values are not give (i.e. `U+271F`) Do i just have to do the math?  Also is there a way to use the UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @Startec updated about utf-8. You can use 16-bit values the same way, f.ex. \u271f -> ✟

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not support UTF-8 strings. All JavaScript strings are UCS-2 (but it supports UTF-16-style surrogate pairs). You can escape astral plane characters with two 16-bit characters: `"\ud83c\udc00"`.

```
"".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
// => "d83c"
"".charCodeAt(1).toString(16)
// => "dc00"
console.log("\ud83c\udc00")
// =>
```

This also means that JavaScript doesn't know how to get the correct length of strings containing astrals, and that any indexing or substringing has a chance of being wrong:

```
"".length
// => 2
```